# mi pregunta es como hacer aparecer un select acorde a la seleccion de varios selcts mediante ajax usando un bd mysql y usando php

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

mi archivo de conexion

```
<?php


    class Constantes {
        const HOST = "localhost";
        const USER = "root";
        const PASSWORD = "";
        const DB = "teayudoeps";
    }
    
    class Configuracion extends Constantes{

        public $mysql = NULL;   

        public function conectarBD($bd = Constantes::DB)
        {
            date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
            $this->mysql = new mysqli(Constantes::HOST, Constantes::USER, Constantes::PASSWORD, $bd);   
            mysqli_set_charset($this->mysql, "utf8");   
            return $this->mysql;

        }

        
        public function consulta($query)
        {           
            $i = 0;
            $contenedor = array();  
            $result = mysqli_query($this->mysql, $query) or die("Error en la consulta: $query ".mysqli_error());
            
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                $contenedor[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }
            
            return $contenedor;
        }

        public function actualizacion($query)
        {
            mysqli_query($this->mysql, $query) or die("Error en la consulta: $query ".mysqli_error());
        }

        public function desconectarDB()
        {
                mysqli_close($this->mysql);
        }

    }
    
?>
```

manejo los selects de esta manera
este es el select del municipio es decir el select que depende la ips este select municipio depende del select departamento que es este

```
  <label for="id_departamento" style="position:absolute;right:8.6rem;top:9rem;">Departamento</label>

                    <select id="id_departamento" class="select-css" style="width:190px;">
                        <option value=" 0">Seleccione</option>
                        <?php  
             
                             $conf = new Configuracion();
                                 $conf->conectarBD();                                                                             
                                 $consulta = "SELECT id_departamento,departamento FROM departamentos";
                                 $rst1 = $conf->consulta($consulta);
                                  for($i = 0; $i < count($rst1); $i++)
                             {                                                   
                                echo '<option value="'.$rst1[$i]["id_departamento"].'">'.$rst1[$i]["departamento"].'</option>';                                                    
                                 }
                                $conf->desconectarDB();
                                 ?>
                    </select>
                    <br>
```

Comment: Cómo está relacionada la pregunta del título con el código? Estás haciendo la consulta en el select pero no se entiende por qué mencionas ajax

Comment: disculpame jquery

Comment: se suelen confundir

Comment: Se llaman select anidados, debes usar el evento onchange del select principal onchange="reload()" y el función reload debes cargar un script php que haga la consulta según el campo seleccionado desde el primer select y cargar la respuesta en el segundo select , $('#select2').load("script.php?pid="+myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value);

Comment: me podrias dar un ejemplo?